# Trying to execute "npx typescript --init" "npm ERR! could not determine executable to run"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

What does the error `npm ERR! could not determine executable to run` mean?

I'm trying to initialise a simple nodejs app with typescript and yarn. I've never really used yarn before.

I've ran the commands:
`yarn init`
Which successfully creates a `package.json`
 `npx typescript --init`
Gives me the above error message.

Versions:
yarn v1.22.11
npx 7.12.0

I've ran `yarn add typescript` and it gives me:

```
info Direct dependencies
└─ typescript@4.3.5
info All dependencies
└─ typescript@4.3.5
```

But when I try `typescript -v` I get `typescript: command not found`

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, But if you want to create a `tsconfig.json` file then the command I use is `tsc --init`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The fix was to use the command `npx tsc --init`.

I don't know why the tutorial I was following used `npx typescript --init`, but it worked for them and not for me.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on [JimmyTheCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860424/1345635), it works because `tsc` is a dummy package that only installs typescript.

The correct way to solve this without installing yet another package is by using the `-p|--package` option on `npx`. This flag is useful when calling a specific binary from a package.

```sh
npx --package typescript tsc --init
# OR
npx -p typescript tsc --init
```

You can find out more on [npx's documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx).

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to install typescript globaly with `npm install -g typescript` to use the tsc cli `npx tsc --init`